# Using a Map with a non-comparable object

Tags: dictionary, f#

I have `Job` type, equality is defined as the Job's ID being equal.  There should never be two jobs with the same ID.  They aren't comparable though, one job isn't *more* or *less* than another, only equal or not.

```fsharp
type JobId = JobId of string

[<CustomEquality; NoComparison>]  
type Job = {
    Id: JobId
} with 
    interface System.IEquatable<Job> with 
        member x.Equals y = x.Id = y.Id

type Resource = { 
    Id: string
    Capacity: float
    Usage:  Map<Job,float>
}
```

The `Map` needs a comparison though.

1. Why does a `Map` need a comparison?
2. What structure should I use?  (I assume I could use an `IDictionary` but I'm trying to stay functional.)

Comment: I would advise you to use `JobId` as the map key, not `Job`, and don't override `Equals`, just check for ID equality. It's a more functional/idiomatic F# style: data is just dumb data. And it makes this particular problem go away.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox it feels like a cheat though.  The usage relates to the Job, not the Job's ID.  It'd also mean in the future, I'd have to find the Job with that ID in a collection in order to find out about it.

Comment: It's not a cheat, it's just simple :) Yes, you might have another `Map<JobId, Job>` to get the actual job details. This way things are separated appropriately.

Comment: I concur with @TheQuickBrownFox. It looks simple and idiomatic.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Think about a change in the future where the ID now has a version as well.  If equally is defined externally then you'll have a lot of places to fix it.  If Job encapsulates that definition then it's a trivial change.  `IEquatable` is definitely the correct way to go.

Comment: If ID has a version as well then it's not just an ID. I'm not suggesting that you define equality externally, just always use the `=` operator. It's a different way of thinking where you don't do encapsulation in that OO sense. Of course you may have technical reasons to do it your way too. It's just something you rarely see in F# code because it's not the functional style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, F#'s `Map` is [implemented as a balanced binary tree (specifically, an AVL tree)](http://fdatamining.blogspot.com/2010/08/reading-f-projects-part-ii-f-set.html), which requires comparison of its key types to be able to decide where in the tree any item belongs. For a hash map that does not require comparison, the [`PersistentHashMap` type from FSharpx.Collections](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/PersistentHashMap.html) is probably what you want.

Comment: That may well do the trick.  A tack on question (if I may), if comparison is needed for the tree, would there be any reason not to default to the hash code (or some arbitrary constant instance value)?

Comment: I'm not sure why they didn't choose the hash code as the key, so all I can do is speculate. It's possible that when the `Map` class was implemented, [Phil Bagwell's paper on Hash-Array Mapped Trees](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/64398/files/idealhashtrees.pdf) (which is what PersistentHashMap implements) was not yet published, so AVL trees were still considered state-of-the-art at the time. But I haven't researched the history of the `Map` implementation in FSharp.Core, so it's very possible that that speculation is wrong. Someone better informed than me might be able to answer that.

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe I can track down one on the F# boffins on the Slack workspace.

Comment: A benefit with `Map` is that it is sorted on the key, hash maps has pseudo random sort order. Also, hash maps performance suffer if the hash function is not generating a good enough spread. You can also use knowledge of the hashing functions to create DOS attacks. With that said, persistent hash maps are good.

Comment: Also note that you need a hash function to use persistent hash maps. Equals is not enough.